# uwsgi through supervisor too many open files

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord, file-descriptors

I have uWSGI set up through supervisor on a ubuntu 12.04 box and lately I noticed that when trying to tail the logs (all the logs in that user account) I get message that `too many files opened` , uWSGI is running as a not root user, I changed the hard and soft limit for this user and rebooted the machine and that fixed the issue. This box has just uwsgi running and my code deployment process stop supervisor which sends a INT signal to the uwsgi process and then start it after performing some operations.
I want to conform that sending INT does make uWSGI close the files it has opened over time?

If not what is a better way to stop uWSGI so that it takes care of its opened files?

uWSGI docs [uWSGI Docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Management.html) says that SIGHUP would reload the server and would close the files it has opened but my requirements are stopping and starting uwsgi.

supervisor-uwsgi section

```
[program:uwsgi]
command=uwsgi --ini abcd.ini --gevent 200
autostart=False
stderr_logfile=/mnt/log/uwsgi.err.log
stdout_logfile=/mnt/log/uwsgi.log
stopsignal=INT
```

Any thoughts please?